# Magento 1.9.4 override Inventory tab template

Tags: magento-1.9, module, stock, inventory

I would like to override the template file used for the inventory tab in admin product edit section.

This is located by default at:

/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml

I have made a custom module to achieve this and done all the requisite steps:

**Config.xml**

```
    <adminhtml>
       <layout>
            <updates>
                <vish_stockMovements>
                    <file>vish_stockmovements.xml</file>
                </vish_stockMovements>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
```

**vish_stockmovements.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <layout>
      <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="tab_inventory">
         <action method="setTemplate"> 
           <template>vish/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml</template> 
         </action>
        </reference>
      </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
     </layout>
```

**inventory.phtml**

```
<?php if ($this->isReadonly()):?>
<?php $_readonly = ' disabled="disabled" ';?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php $_readonly = '';?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">
        <h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Inventory') ?></h4>
    </div>
    <fieldset>

        <legend><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Inventory') ?></legend>
        <table cellspacing="0" class="form-list" id="table_cataloginventory">
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_manage_stock"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Manage Stock') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value"><select id="inventory_manage_stock" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][manage_stock]" class="select" <?php echo $_readonly;?>>
                <option value="1"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Yes') ?></option>
                <option value="0"<?php if ($this->getConfigFieldValue('manage_stock') == 0): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No') ?></option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" id="inventory_manage_stock_default" value="<?php echo $this->getDefaultConfigValue('manage_stock'); ?>" />

            <?php $_checked = ($this->getFieldValue('use_config_manage_stock') || $this->IsNew()) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_manage_stock" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][use_config_manage_stock]" value="1" <?php echo $_checked ?> onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode);" class="checkbox" <?php echo $_readonly;?>/>
            <label for="inventory_use_config_manage_stock" class="normal"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Use Config Settings') ?></label>
            <?php if (!$this->isReadonly()):?><script type="text/javascript">toggleValueElements($('inventory_use_config_manage_stock'), $('inventory_use_config_manage_stock').parentNode);</script><?php endif; ?></td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td class="label"><label for="stock_change_reason"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Stock Change Reason') ?></label></td>
 <td class="value">
<?php var_dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());?>
    <select id="stock_change_reason" name="stock_change_reason" class="select" <?php echo $_readonly;?>>
    <?php foreach($this->getStockReason() as $eachOption) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $eachOption['value'];?>"> <?php echo $eachOption['label'];?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </td>  
</tr>


<?php if(!$this->getProduct()->isComposite()): ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_qty"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty') ?><span class="required">*</span></label></td>
            <td class="value">
                <?php if (!$_readonly):?>
                <input type="hidden" id="original_inventory_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][original_inventory_qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getFieldValue('qty')*1 ?>"/>
                <?php endif;?>
                <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-number" id="inventory_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getFieldValue('qty')*1 ?>" <?php echo $_readonly;?>/>
            </td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_min_qty"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty for Item\'s Status to Become Out of Stock') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value"><input type="text" class="input-text validate-number" id="inventory_min_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][min_qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getFieldValue('min_qty')*1 ?>" <?php echo $_readonly;?>/>

            <?php $_checked = ($this->getFieldValue('use_config_min_qty') || $this->IsNew()) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_min_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][use_config_min_qty]" value="1" <?php echo $_checked ?> onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode);" <?php echo $_readonly;?> />
            <label for="inventory_use_config_min_qty" class="normal"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Use Config Settings') ?></label>
            <?php if (!$this->isReadonly()):?><script type="text/javascript">toggleValueElements($('inventory_use_config_min_qty'), $('inventory_use_config_min_qty').parentNode);</script><?php endif; ?></td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_min_sale_qty"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value"><input type="text" class="input-text validate-number" id="inventory_min_sale_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][min_sale_qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getFieldValue('min_sale_qty')*1 ?>" <?php echo $_readonly;?>/>

            <?php $_checked = ($this->getFieldValue('use_config_min_sale_qty') || $this->IsNew()) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_min_sale_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][use_config_min_sale_qty]" value="1" <?php echo $_checked ?> onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode);" class="checkbox" <?php echo $_readonly;?> />
            <label for="inventory_use_config_min_sale_qty" class="normal"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Use Config Settings') ?></label>
            <?php if (!$this->isReadonly()):?><script type="text/javascript">toggleValueElements($('inventory_use_config_min_sale_qty'), $('inventory_use_config_min_sale_qty').parentNode);</script><?php endif; ?></td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_max_sale_qty"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value"><input type="text" class="input-text validate-number" id="inventory_max_sale_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][max_sale_qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getFieldValue('max_sale_qty')*1 ?>" <?php echo $_readonly;?> />

            <?php $_checked = ($this->getFieldValue('use_config_max_sale_qty') || $this->IsNew()) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_max_sale_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][use_config_max_sale_qty]" value="1" <?php echo $_checked ?> onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode);" class="checkbox" <?php echo $_readonly;?> />
            <label for="inventory_use_config_max_sale_qty" class="normal"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Use Config Settings') ?></label>
            <?php if (!$this->isReadonly()):?><script type="text/javascript">toggleValueElements($('inventory_use_config_max_sale_qty'), $('inventory_use_config_max_sale_qty').parentNode);</script><?php endif; ?></td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php if($this->canUseQtyDecimals()): ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_is_qty_decimal"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty Uses Decimals') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value"><select id="inventory_is_qty_decimal" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][is_qty_decimal]" class="select" <?php echo $_readonly;?>>
                <option value="0"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No') ?></option>
                <option value="1"<?php if($this->getFieldValue('is_qty_decimal')==1): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Yes') ?></option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php if (!$this->isVirtual()) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_is_decimal_divided"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Can be Divided into Multiple Boxes for Shipping') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value"><select id="inventory_is_decimal_divided" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][is_decimal_divided]" class="select" <?php echo $_readonly;?>>
                <option value="0"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No') ?></option>
                <option value="1"<?php if($this->getFieldValue('is_decimal_divided') == 1): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Yes') ?></option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_backorders"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Backorders') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value"><select id="inventory_backorders" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][backorders]" class="select" <?php echo $_readonly;?>>
            <?php foreach ($this->getBackordersOption() as $option): ?>
                <?php $_selected = ($option['value'] == $this->getFieldValue('backorders')) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>" <?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $option['label'] ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>

            <?php $_checked = ($this->getFieldValue('use_config_backorders') || $this->IsNew()) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_backorders" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][use_config_backorders]" value="1" <?php echo $_checked ?> onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode);" class="checkbox" <?php echo $_readonly;?> />
            <label for="inventory_use_config_backorders" class="normal"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Use Config Settings') ?></label>
            <?php if (!$this->isReadonly()):?><script type="text/javascript">toggleValueElements($('inventory_use_config_backorders'), $('inventory_use_config_backorders').parentNode);</script><?php endif; ?></td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_notify_stock_qty"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Notify for Quantity Below') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value"><input type="text" class="input-text validate-number" id="inventory_notify_stock_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][notify_stock_qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getFieldValue('notify_stock_qty')*1 ?>" <?php echo $_readonly;?>/>

            <?php $_checked = ($this->getFieldValue('use_config_notify_stock_qty') || $this->IsNew()) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_notify_stock_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][use_config_notify_stock_qty]" value="1" <?php echo $_checked ?> onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode);" class="checkbox" <?php echo $_readonly;?>/>
            <label for="inventory_use_config_notify_stock_qty" class="normal"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Use Config Settings') ?></label>
            <?php if (!$this->isReadonly()):?><script type="text/javascript">toggleValueElements($('inventory_use_config_notify_stock_qty'), $('inventory_use_config_notify_stock_qty').parentNode);</script><?php endif; ?></td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_enable_qty_increments"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Enable Qty Increments') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value"><select id="inventory_enable_qty_increments" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][enable_qty_increments]" class="select" <?php echo $_readonly;?>>
                <option value="1"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Yes') ?></option>
                <option value="0"<?php if ($this->getConfigFieldValue('enable_qty_increments') == 0): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No') ?></option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" id="inventory_enable_qty_increments_default" value="<?php echo $this->getDefaultConfigValue('enable_qty_increments'); ?>" />

            <?php $_checked = ($this->getFieldValue('use_config_enable_qty_increments') || $this->IsNew()) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_enable_qty_increments" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][use_config_enable_qty_increments]" value="1" <?php echo $_checked ?> onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode);" class="checkbox" <?php echo $_readonly;?>/>
            <label for="inventory_use_config_enable_qty_increments" class="normal"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Use Config Settings') ?></label>
            <?php if (!$this->isReadonly()):?><script type="text/javascript">toggleValueElements($('inventory_use_config_enable_qty_increments'), $('inventory_use_config_enable_qty_increments').parentNode);</script><?php endif; ?></td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_qty_increments"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty Increments') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value">
                <input type="text" class="input-text validate-digits" id="inventory_qty_increments" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][qty_increments]" value="<?php echo $this->getFieldValue('qty_increments')*1 ?>" <?php echo $_readonly;?>/>
                <?php $_checked = ($this->getFieldValue('use_config_qty_increments') || $this->IsNew()) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>
                <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_qty_increments" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][use_config_qty_increments]" value="1" <?php echo $_checked ?> onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode);" class="checkbox" <?php echo $_readonly;?>/>
                <label for="inventory_use_config_qty_increments" class="normal"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Use Config Settings') ?></label>
                <?php if (!$this->isReadonly()):?><script type="text/javascript">toggleValueElements($('inventory_use_config_qty_increments'), $('inventory_use_config_qty_increments').parentNode);</script><?php endif; ?></td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="inventory_stock_availability"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Stock Availability') ?></label></td>
            <td class="value"><select id="inventory_stock_availability" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][is_in_stock]" class="select" <?php echo $_readonly;?>>
            <?php foreach ($this->getStockOption() as $option): ?>
                <?php $_selected = ($option['value'] == $this->getFieldValue('is_in_stock')) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>" <?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $option['label'] ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function changeManageStockOption()
    {
        var manageStock = $('inventory_use_config_manage_stock').checked
            ? $('inventory_manage_stock_default').value
            : $('inventory_manage_stock').value;
        var catalogInventoryNotManageStockFields = {
            inventory_min_sale_qty: true,
            inventory_max_sale_qty: true,
            inventory_enable_qty_increments : true,
            inventory_qty_increments: true
        };

        $$('#table_cataloginventory tr').each(function(el) {
            if (el == $('inventory_manage_stock').up(1)) {
                return;
            }

            for (field in catalogInventoryNotManageStockFields) {
                if ($(field) && ($(field).up(1) == el)) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            el[manageStock == 1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
        });

        return true;
    }

    function applyEnableQtyIncrements() {
        var enableQtyIncrements = $('inventory_use_config_enable_qty_increments').checked
            ? $('inventory_enable_qty_increments_default').value
            : $('inventory_enable_qty_increments').value;

        $('inventory_qty_increments').up('tr')[enableQtyIncrements == 1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    }

    function applyEnableDecimalDivided() {
    <?php if (!$this->isVirtual()) : ?>
        $('inventory_is_decimal_divided').up('tr').hide();
        <?php endif; ?>
        $('inventory_qty_increments').removeClassName('validate-digits').removeClassName('validate-number');
        $('inventory_min_sale_qty').removeClassName('validate-digits').removeClassName('validate-number');
        if ($('inventory_is_qty_decimal').value == 1) {
        <?php if (!$this->isVirtual()) : ?>
            $('inventory_is_decimal_divided').up('tr').show();
            <?php endif; ?>
            $('inventory_qty_increments').addClassName('validate-number');
            $('inventory_min_sale_qty').addClassName('validate-number');
        } else {
            $('inventory_qty_increments').addClassName('validate-digits');
            $('inventory_min_sale_qty').addClassName('validate-digits');
        }
    }

    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        if ($('inventory_manage_stock') && $('inventory_use_config_manage_stock')) {
            Event.observe($('inventory_manage_stock'), 'change', changeManageStockOption);
            Event.observe($('inventory_use_config_manage_stock'), 'change', changeManageStockOption);
            changeManageStockOption();
        }
        if ($('inventory_enable_qty_increments') && $('inventory_use_config_enable_qty_increments')) {
            Event.observe($('inventory_enable_qty_increments'), 'change', applyEnableQtyIncrements);
            Event.observe($('inventory_use_config_enable_qty_increments'), 'change', applyEnableQtyIncrements);
            applyEnableQtyIncrements();
        }
        if ($('inventory_is_qty_decimal') && $('inventory_qty_increments') && $('inventory_min_sale_qty')) {
            Event.observe($('inventory_is_qty_decimal'), 'change', applyEnableDecimalDivided);
            applyEnableDecimalDivided();
        }
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

I have debugged and deduced the layout update is being called successfully. So, looks like a reference issue. What would the reference be for overriding this template file?

Answer (score 1):

The reference name `tab_inventory` doesn't exist in handle `adminhtml_catalog_product_edit`. The inventory template is set directly in the `__construct()` method of class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Inventory`.

A simpler and easier approach is to create a custom adminhtml theme. You can find detailed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448983/magento-override-adminhtml-template-file). This way you can override any template by copying the corresponding core file to your custom theme folder and modifying them.

Comment: Indeed you are right. I figured it out yesterday. But could not post an answer. I will update and accept your answer.